# What kind of diode package/case is "case-17"?

Tags: diodes, components, packages, cases, bom

The Russian company asked me to purchase several elements for the production of the device.

Among the elements in the BOM there were two "5 watts" zener diodes

- 1N5342B at 6.8 Volts
- 1N5349B at 12 Volts

For both diodes in the column *"Case Type"* was written *"DO-СASE17"*.

[image: BOM]

Seeing this name of the type of case, I am a little surprised, because I have always used diodes in cases with names like *"DO-15"* or *"DO-204AC"*. At first, I decided that it was just a mistake and started looking for a diode by its parameters - but it turned out that some manufacturers, for example, *"ON Semiconductor"*, do not write standard types of coruses in the documentation for diodes, but on 7 page - write such lines in the header of the case type description:

> SURMETIC 40, AXIAL LEAD
>
> CASE 017AA
>
> ISSUE O

Link to the Datasheet "1N53xx(B, G) Series":
[>>>>> HERE <<<<<](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/1N5333B-D.PDF)

Screenshot this page:
[image: Screenshot]

**Actually my questions:**

1) What kind of case is this *"CASE-17"*, is it another name for a particular manufacturer?

2) How is this case different from *"DO-xx"* type cases?

3) What does the line *"SURMETIC 40"* mean, is SURMETIC a company producing packaging or something else?

4) What does the line *"ISSUE O"* mean?

**==========================================================**

**============ As a result of proceedings on this issue: ============**

SURMETIC is a trademark specifically "ON-Semiconductor" - for example, in my document [>>>>>HERE<<<<<](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/1N5333B-D.PDF) is written on the last page, quote:

> SURMETIC is a trademark of Semiconductor Components Industries, LLC (SCILLC).

[image: SURMETIC]

**Now it remains to figure it out**

1) What do the other lines mean

2) What actually write in the BOM, in the column "type of housing", instead of the short and well-known DO-15 and DO-204AS

- All together "SURMETIC 40, AXIAL LEAD, CASE 017AA, ISSUE O"
- Or just "017AA." But in this case, not everyone will understand what kind of case it is.

3) Why did ON-Semiconductor come up with their new name for the long-known case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surmetic is a trademark used only(owned) by ON-Semiconductor. It is used to mention the **type of housing**.

Some parts are also JEDEC standard compatible (Surmetic 30, below image for example). Any other assocaited data, only OnSemi supplier can answer. Below image is from [here](https://www.mouser.de/catalog/German/103/565.pdf).
[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank @Umar !
Yes, you are right - for example, on last page in my document is written, quote:
"SURMETIC is a trademark of Semiconductor Components Industries, LLC (SCILLC)."

Now it remains to figure it out
1) What do the lines mean
2) What actually write in the BOM, in the column "type of housing", instead of the short and well-known DO-15 and DO-204AS
- All together "SURMETIC 40, AXIAL LEAD, CASE 017AA, ISSUE O"
- Or just "017AA." But in this case, not everyone will understand what kind of case it is.

3) Why did ON-Semiconductor come up with their new name for the long-known case

Comment: Surmetic 40, axial Lead is sufficient i think